# How to see the .NET MAUI sample application instead of home screen

Tags: maui

I'm just getting started with .NET MAUI and experiencing issues already.
Not sure if all of these issues are related.

This is a new machine and has a fresh installation of Visual Studio.

I Created a new project with the default template - `.NET MAUI App`

1. When I rebuild the solution, it takes more than 4 minutes. This seems too long for a single project. Is this expected or do I need more RAM.
   [image]
2. When I run the project, it loads the home screen and not the application. I'm expecting it to load the .NET MAUI sample application screen with the counter button.

[image]

3. When I close the simulator using the top right `x` icon in the right icons bar, it closes the simulator, but after a few seconds, it opens again.

[image]

4. When I close the simulator the second time, it closes completely but shows an error saying there were deployment errors.

[image]

**Configurations:**

Visual Studio 2022 v17.6.2
Simulator: Pixel 5 - API 33 (Android 13.0 - API 33)
Windows 11 Pro
16 GB RAM

Comment: 1) The next time you Rebuild Solution, it should be faster. And you almost never need to Rebuild; usually you simply Build. 2) You closed emulator too early; it had not finished deploying. It opens emulator long before the packaged app is ready to be sent. Do not close it. Wait until the app appears. This will also be faster the second time.

Comment: This can all be seen in the Output pane. Until you get a line with asterisks, saying Deploy … succeeded or failed, wait.

Comment: To enhance the performance for Android emulator, you could use [Hardware acceleration for emulator performance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?pivots=windows)

Comment: I have not heard from you for a couple of days. May I know if you still meet this issue?

Comment: @LiqunShen-MSFT I had to restart my machine. Then it started working but it takes some time. The Hardware acceleration was already enabled. Thank you for the help.

Comment: So restart the machine you mean make it much faster?

Comment: No restart did not make it any faster. It still takes 4-6 minutes on a rebuild and around 1-3 minutes to open the emulator. So, I'm switching to React Native now :)

Comment: The Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) is deprecated from emulator 33.x.x.x, and has been replaced by [AEHD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/emulator/hardware-acceleration#accelerate-with-aehd) on Intel processors.  Also here are some [performance issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/emulator/troubleshooting#performance-issues). You could have a look if you like.

Answer (score 1):

The Android emulator runs too slowly if hardware acceleration is not available on the computer that runs it.

In order to maximize Android Emulator performance, the following virtualization technologies are available for accelerating the Android emulator:

1.[The Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/emulator/hardware-acceleration#accelerate-with-hyper-v)

2.[The Android Emulator hypervisor driver (AEHD).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/emulator/hardware-acceleration#accelerate-with-aehd)

For more info, please refer to [How to enable hardware acceleration with Android emulators (Hyper-V & AEHD)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/emulator/hardware-acceleration).

Hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible scenarios.

1. Android simulator is launched and is running, but it cannot be connected from Visual Studio (Simulator/Visual Studio bug probably).
2. Android simulator window is closed, but its processes are still running and do not allow to launch new Android simulator instance.

My solution:

1. Open Task Manager
2. Go to "Details tab"
3. Find "emulator.exe" process
4. Mouse right click on this process and select "End Process Tree"

After that try to compile and deploy your application again. It should work.

[image: removingSimulatorProcesses]